# Why OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter does not perform dirty-checking?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I use JPA lazy loading in a Spring MVC controller (but it could be a casual servlet). I find a Book entity which has a @ManyToOne lazy relationship with Author.

```
@Entity
public class Book extends BaseEntity {
    private String isbn;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Author author;

    private int price;
```

A SpringMVC controller does a find on it (I simplified the code for the sake of the example):

```
@Controller
public class EditBookController {

    @Autowired    BookDao bDao;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/updatebook"})
    public String updateBook(@RequestParam("id")Long id) {
        Book book = bDao.find(id);
        System.out.println( book.getAuthor().getFirstName() ); // Lazy loading FAIL
        return “bookView”;
    }
```

BookDao.find() is defined in its ancestor BaseRepository:

```
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class BaseRepository<E extends BaseEntity> {
    Class entityClass;

    public E find(Long id){
        return ( E ) em.find( entityClass, id );
    }
```

Of course it triggers a LazyInit exception in the controller. So I add the filter OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and it works fine: the book entity is not detached anymore in the controller.

Now, I'd like to modify the book in the controller. For example, I call book.setPrice(4);

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/updatebook"})
public String updateBook(@RequestParam("id")Long id) {
    Book book = bDao.find(id);
    System.out.println( book.getAuthor().getFirstName() ); // Lazy loading OK
    book.setPrice(4);
    return “bookView”;
}
```

I expected Hibernate to do its dirty checking, detect that book's value has been changed, and save it. It would be triggered by the OpenEntityInViewFilter when closing the EntityMangager.

But my (non detached) managed entity triggers no update to the DB, unless I explicitely call em.merge(book).

Can somebody explain to me why is the dirty checking not active in this case?
Many thanks!

Spring v3.1.2
Hibernate v4.1.4

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to manage the transactions?

If spring is managing them, then you need to add @Transactional in your controller method. The @Transactional annotation is used to demarcate where a transaction starts, so the issue you're having is that spring/hibernate doesn't know that any changes need to be persisted when `updateBook()` returns. The OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter doesn't commit a transaction (but you might want to write your own implementation that does a commit).

In my view (someone else might disagree), it's a good practice to annotate the entry points of your application with @Transactional, they might be controllers, JMS consumers or anything else.

Comment: Thanks Augusto. I've added @Transactional at the controller level (EditBookController), but the entity is still not saved. Any other idea?